# MongoDB Query where not all

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to write a query in MongDB to select all rows where users has partially completed their profiles.

Where f1 or f2 or f3 is null or '' but not where the three fields are null or ''

I mean where one or two of the three fields are null but not the three fields

**I have tried this which does not return expected records:**
**UPDATED**

```
var query = {
      $or:[
            {"profile.public.f1": {$in: [null, false, '']}},
            {"profile.public.f2": {$in: [null, false, '']}},
            {"profile.public.f3": {$in: [null, false, '']}}
      ]
};
```

This query is used in nodejs like so:

```
function GetDocument(model, query, projection, extension, callback) {
    var query = db[model].find(query, projection, extension.options);
    if (extension.populate) {
       query.populate(extension.populate);
    }
    if (extension.sort) {
      query.sort(extension.sort);
    }
    query.exec(function (err, docs) {
    if (extension.count) {
        query.count(function (err, docs) {
            callback(err, docs);
        });
    } else {
        callback(err, docs);
    }
  });
}
```

Then later:

```
db.GetDocument('users', query, {}, {}, function (err, docdata) {
      console.log(docdata)          
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using $where:

```
> db.createCollection("t");
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.t.insert({f1:'a',f2:'',f3:''});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.t.insert({f1:'',f2:'',f3:null});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.t.insert({f1:'',f2:'',f3:''});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.t.insert({f1:'',f2:''});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.t.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aab60118633becf0ac4f80"), "f1" : "a", "f2" : "", "f3" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aab60718633becf0ac4f81"), "f1" : "", "f2" : "", "f3" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aab61018633becf0ac4f82"), "f1" : "", "f2" : "", "f3" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aab65618633becf0ac4f83"), "f1" : "", "f2" : "" }
> var q = {$where: function() {return ((this.f1.length||'') + (this.f2.length||'') +(this.f3 || '').length) >0;}};
> db.t.find(q);
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58aab60118633becf0ac4f80"), "f1" : "a", "f2" : "", "f3" : "" }
```

query breakdown:

```
{
  $where: function(){
    return((this.f1.length||'')+(this.f2.length||'')+(this.f3||'').length)>0;
  }
};
```

where should return true => sum of String(field value) must be grater then zero. This way uf fieldN = '', then its length is equal to zero, if all three are equal to zero, their sum will be zero (0+0+0)=0, but if at least one value <> '', then it will return true, this way fulfilling where clause.

Now the problem is that null.length wont work, so we have either wrap it up in String(null) or give any suitable value if it fails, so we come to semantically wrong, but shorter and working `this.f1.length||''` if first fails the second works. operator `OR` picks up first working value...

if you want it in nodejs, not mongo shell, here's example:

```
vao@vao-VirtualBox:~$ nodejs
> var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
...   co = require('co'),
...   assert = require('assert');
undefined
>
> co(function*() {
...   var db = yield MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
...   var col = db.collection('t');
...   var q = {$where: function() {return ((this.f1.length||'') + (this.f2.length||'') +(this.f3 || '').length) >0;}};
...   //var cursor = col.find({f1.length:{$gt:0}});
...   var cursor = col.find({f1:"a"});
...   col.find().toArray(function(err, items) {});
...   var stream = col.find(q).stream();
...   stream.on("data", function(item) {});
...   stream.on("end", function() {});
...
...   while(yield cursor.hasNext()) {
...     var doc = yield cursor.next();
...     console.dir(doc);
...   }
...
...   db.close();
... }).catch(function(err) {
...   console.log(err.stack);
... });
Promise { <pending> }
>
> { _id:
   ObjectID {
     _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
     id:
      Buffer {
        '0': 88,
        '1': 172,
        '2': 1,
        '3': 143,
        '4': 157,
        '5': 175,
        '6': 27,
        '7': 230,
        '8': 160,
        '9': 208,
        '10': 69,
        '11': 88 } },
  f1: 'a',
  f2: '',
  f3: '' }

(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
>
```

Comment: Please can you help to explain this in detail: break it down: `var q = {$where: function() {return ((this.f1.length||'') + (this.f2.length||'') +(this.f3 || '').length) >0;}};`

Comment: updated answer. sorry for typos - home laptop is very uncomfortable

Comment: Vao Tsun thanks for all your efforts. Can this work in nodejs?

Comment: Vao Tsun Thanks. The fields are like this "profile.public.f2", "profile.public.f2" and "profile.public.f3" can this work `this.profile.public.f2.length||''` does n't seem to be working. all the records are returned

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136248/discussion-between-digitlimit-and-vao-tsun).